# Adding dynamic links to ASP.NET repeater control

Tags: arrays, asp.net, mapping, href, repeater

I have the following repeater in an ASPX file. It's a five-block slider that showcases 4 different activities, with a booking button at the bottom. My goal is to replace the button href dynamically, creating a sort of map that pairs the ID of the activity with my links.
E.g.
`PackageId` 54 = https://link1
So for the activity with `PackageId` 54 I want the button to have `href="https://link1"` instead of `href="BookSession.aspx?Id=<%#Eval("PackageId")%>"`

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptData">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <div class="card ">
                                        <ul class="text-center">
                                            <li>
                                                <img src="<%#Eval("iCon").ToString()+"?"+DateTime.Now.Ticks %>" <%--.Replace("../Photo","https://Images.thesmashroom.com")style="height:70px; width:60px"--%> alt="" /></li>
                                            <li>
                                                 <h2 class="redColor"><%#Eval("PackageName") %></h2>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <h4 class="text-white"><%# string.Join("<br />", Eval("OneLineDescription").ToString().Split(new []{","},StringSplitOptions.None)) %></h4>
                                            </li>
                                            
                                            <li>
                                                <h4 class="text-white"><%#"AED "+ Eval("Price") %></h4>
                                            </li>  

                                            <!--<li><p class="text-white">( <%# Eval("total_persion") %> person / 1 room )</p></li> -->
<li><p class="text-white">( <%# Eval("total_persion") %> person)</p></li>                                           
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li> 
                                                <a href="BookSession.aspx?Id=<%#Eval("PackageId")%>" >Book Now</a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
```

I tried to add a php array mapping the list of  4 IDs with my list of 4 links and of course it didn't work with ASP.NET.
I tried to search for an ASP.NET version of the same array, no luck.
Any suggerstion?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, string> linkMapping = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
    {54, "https://link1"},
    {55, "https://link2"},
    {56, "https://link3"},
    {57, "https://link4"}
};
```

Then modify the button in the repeater's ItemTemplate as follows:

```
<a href='<%# linkMapping[(int)Eval("PackageId")] %>' >Book Now</a>
```

And in the Page_Load event, bind the data to the repeater:

```
rptData.DataSource = data; // replace "data" with the actual data source
rptData.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not familiar with ASP, where can I actually add the Dictionary? Do I need to wrap it with a particular tag? And where do I find the Page_Load event?

Comment: Well, how you determine that say 54 is to be link 1, and how do you determine that 56 is supposed to be link3? Is that information from the database? How are you deciding that these numbers have a particular link? Seems to me that you would replace the "link" with a simple button you click on, that button click would get/use/have the current data row (of the repeater) for your use in code behind, and thus you could/would/should/can use a simple button click in place of that hyperlink. So, where is this "link" vs a "number" information defined? As such, you may well not need dictionary.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I know that each of the 4 items have an ID because I can see from the frontend that the current link of each item ends with that number. I don't have access to the database. I am integrating a third party software so I have my own link for each item, that's how I know how to pair them. If I replace the hyperlink with a simple button I would have all the 5 buttons in the repeater linkined to the same url.

Comment: no, see my code below. You can certainly use a case statement, or code behind to jump to whatever link you want. And no, you have ONE button, that gets repeated, and that button is then free to navigate based on that id.

Answer (score 0):

it would be likely better to drop the hyper link, and simple use/have a button click in place of that link.

The only real question is how and where do you define that 54 is to be link 1, and how do you determine that 56 is supposed to be link3? Is that information from the database?

So, you can drop in a simple button into that repeater, and when clicked on, it can "use" or "enjoy" information about that one row clicked on, and that includes the "id" and the "link" we want to use based on that ID.

However, I can't imagine that these numbers are "random", and thus a reasonable guess is that this "id" has some information associated (some place - maybe the database) that holds information as to what link is to be used.

While we wait for you to come back and provide that information, here is how a repeater button works, and how it can "pick up" the current row information, and pluck out values from that one one. (and the button can even then hit the database to pull more information - even information that you don't necessary include in that repeater row for display.

So, say a few rows of some information about fighter jets.

When we click on the button, we can then get/have information about the rows.

So, say this markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"  >
    <ItemTemplate>                
        <div class="mybox" ">

            <div style="text-align: center; padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px" >
                <asp:Button ID="cmdMyView" runat="server" Text="View"
                    CssClass="btn-info" Style="float: right"
                    OnClick="cmdMyView_Click"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />

                <br />
                <h3><%# Eval("Fighter") %></h3>
                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' Width="170" />
                <h4>Engine</h4>
                <asp:Label ID="EngineLabel2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Engine") %>' />
                <h4>Description</h4>
                <asp:Label ID="DescLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' />
                <br />
            </div>
        </div> 
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And code behind to load is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }


    void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Fighters";
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                Repeater1.DataSource = rstData;
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

and now we see/get this:

[image]

But, note the button code in the above repeater.

```
<asp:Button ID="cmdMyView" runat="server" Text="View"
    CssClass="btn-info" Style="float: right"
    OnClick="cmdMyView_Click"
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
```

So, now code behind is this:

```
protected void cmdMyView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    RepeaterItem rRow = (RepeaterItem)btn.NamingContainer;
    int MyRowIndex = rRow.ItemIndex;
    int MyPK = Convert.ToInt32(btn.CommandArgument);

    Debug.Print("Row index click = " + MyRowIndex);
    Debug.Print("Pk data base = " + MyPK);

    // get say the engine from the row click
    Label lblEngine = (Label)rRow.FindControl("EngineLabel2");
    Debug.Print("engine = " + lblEngine.Text);            

    // get more infomraiton from database - based on pk "ID"
    // etc. etc.
}
```

And thus if I click on the view button, we get this:

output:

```
Row index click = 3
Pk data base = 4
engine = 1 × Pratt & Whitney F135-PW-100 afterburning turbofan
```

So, in place of a hyper link, it really in most cases less effort to just drop in a button, and then use that, and as above shows, we can get information about the given row clicked on, or use the database PK id we passed to code behind to do whatever we want, including that of a navigation based on that ID value.

So, the only remain question is how and where do  you decide that say id 53 is to be some particular link? (you certainly do NOT want to hand code, or hard code such values in code behind, but explain how and where this information exists to determine that link, and then use code behind to build/create and navigate to wherever you want based on this information.

So, we can I suppose hard code based on that say PK id, say like this:

```
// get more information from database - based on pk "ID"
// etc. etc.

switch (MyPK)
{
    case 5:
        Response.Redirect(@"~/FightersInfoClass5.aspx");
        break;
    case 12:
        Response.Redirect(@"~/FightersInfoClass12.aspx");
        break;
}
```

Or, as suggested in other post - use a dictionary or some format.

Say, like this code (assuming we have MyPK).

```
        Dictionary<int, string> linkMapping = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
                {54, @"~/Page2.aspx"},
                {55, @"~/Page3.aspx"},
                {56, @"~/Page4.aspx"},
                {57, @"~/Page5.aspx"}
            };

        Response.Redirect(linkMapping[MyPK]);
```

And, if you want, you could create/use/have the expression in markup, but often it somewhat more messy to do so, means two places to maintain, but either approach is fine - much comes down to your personal preference. however, ONLY code behind, or markup tags with runat="server" can use the above "~/" to mean the root base of the web site. In JavaScript, or markup, you can't use "~/" to represent the root of the site, so if such links are external, then you want to use the full URL, but for internal links to the given site, then you can use/enjoy use of "~/" in code behind - and thus such links are easier in code behind and a response.redirect().

Comment: The ID of the 4 items is in the database, which as I said before I don't have access to. But I can deduce the 4 IDs (53, 54, 55, 56) thanks to the links that the current buttons have (e.g. https://website.com/BookSession.aspx?Id=53).
I know the external links because I generated them using the software I'm trying to integrate into this site.
My goal is having for each item an anchor tag with href, and each of the 4 buttons in the repeater with the related external link.

Comment: The 1st answer seems also like a good solution but I don't know where and how to place the linkmapping and where I find the Page_Load event. Sorry, my knowledge of ASP.NET is quite limited.

Comment: To write code, change code and modify that asp.net application? You need the source code application, and need to be running Visual Studio. There not really any other way to make basic changes to markup and the code behind that drives such sites.  Remember, asp.net web sites are not based on just markup, but based on writing c# or vb.net code behind. As such, most code tends to be code behind, and not markup code. The asp.net "system" thus cranks out the markup, and you don't care, since we just feed the repeater a data source and don't even need/have a loop.

Comment: So, while editing the aspx page in Visual Studio, just right click, and choose view code. Visual studio will now move/fip/show you the code behind, including the page load event. You can't JUST edit the aspx page, you need to edit that page from Visual Studio, since that web page as a c#/vb.net "page" class that drives the page. So, from VS, can you now see/view the code when you open a page from VS, and then right click and choose view code?